# Googlebot and other spiders cannot access our Asp.net site in iis8 (only browsers work)

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-crawler, googlebot, google-crawlers

Googlebot and other spiders cannot access my site at all they get server error 500 and cannot crawl or whatever, when using google fetch as its fetches and rendering  but when it gonna crawl it gets the error below.  all kind of spiders gets the same error. Is it something i must put in the code to allow spiders like googlebot?  the robots.txt is fine and also the sitemap.

the error code from the spiders or googlebot is this below:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>   Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.] Utbildningsportalen.WebUI.Controllers.HomeController.Index()
>   +28 lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +86 System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +228
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +89
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +38
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +74

Edit 1:

HomeController method

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (!Request.UserLanguages[0].Contains("sv"))
    {
        var engStart = startHelper.allEngStartPages().FirstOrDefault();

        engStart.RowNumber = 12 / engStart.PresentationObjectsPerRow;

        return View(engStart);
    }

    var start = startHelper.allSweStartPages().FirstOrDefault();

    start.RowNumber = 12 / start.PresentationObjectsPerRow;

    return View(start);
}
```

Edit2:
And then we tried  with this and it still couldn't access the site:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    StartpageViewModel start;

    if (Request.UserLanguages != null)
    {
        if (!Request.UserLanguages[0].Contains("sv"))
            start = startHelper.allEngStartPages().FirstOrDefault();
        else
            start = startHelper.allSweStartPages().FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else
        start = startHelper.StartPagesByLang("sv");

    start.RowNumber = 12 / start.PresentationObjectsPerRow;

    return View(start);
}
```

Comment: xenu link sleuth gets  same error too

Comment: Show us the Index method on your HomeController.

Comment: `code` public ActionResult Index()

        {

            if (!Request.UserLanguages[0].Contains("sv"))

            {

                var engStart = startHelper.allEngStartPages().FirstOrDefault();

                engStart.RowNumber = 12 / engStart.PresentationObjectsPerRow;

                return View(engStart);

            }

            var start = startHelper.allSweStartPages().FirstOrDefault();

            start.RowNumber = 12 / start.PresentationObjectsPerRow;

            return View(start);

        }

Comment: Don't post your code in comments. Code should be edited into your question, and you should check to make sure it's formatted properly. Please review [MCVE] so you'll know what to include in your question next time.

Comment: sorry im new, i edited it and put it in my question

Comment: I would first focus on `Request.UserLanguages`: does that have a value when a bot requests that page? Next, do not assume that bots supply cookies, such as a session cookie - you may have an empty session.

Comment: we will look into this thanks :)

Comment: We updated the code    please look  in the question and scroll down... it still didn't work   googlebot and  other crawlers, xenu lin sleuth cannot access the site.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your exception occurs in the Index method, I expect the UserLanguages property is empty, or even Null.

Check if it is null and has an index 0 before checking if it's Swedish. You could use those nifty null conditional indexer operators.

If that is in fact the problem; it's interesting bots dont send a accept-language header.

Comment: We updated the code    please look  in the question and scroll down... it still didn't work   googlebot and  other crawlers, xenu lin sleuth cannot access the site.

Comment: You implemented only half of what I recommended. Just because Request.UserLanguages is not null does not mean it has an index 0, or that index 0 has a value.